# How to make all queries to model inherit a calculated sql column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to every query involving my `Issue` model appends another column to its rows. 
In my case this column is a boolean if the issue's created_at date from now passed a total of 12 hours (business hours: 8:00 am - 18:00 pm, excluding saturdays and mondays).

```
SELECT *, hours > 12 as alert FROM
  ( 
  SELECT *, 
        (SELECT count(*) - 1 AS work_hours
            FROM   generate_series ( created_at
                                    , now()
                                    , interval '1h') h
            WHERE  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM h) < 6
            AND    h::time >= '08:00'::time
            AND    h::time <  '18:00'::time) as hours

  FROM issues
  ) as issues_with_alert
```

This will return all issues columns such as `id`, `title`, `description`..., plus the calculated one: `alert`

I thought making a sql view `issues_view` and change table name on the model to the view ones.

```
self.table_name = "issues_view"
```

Then the view should care about all the queries from it inheriting the `alert` column.

But it seems rails is not fully prepared for that and monkey patches should be made:

http://mentalized.net/journal/2006/03/27/using_sql_server_views_as_rails_tables/
and other problems I found.

Other one is to implements the method on the `Issue` model:

```
def self.default_scope

end
```

But I don't know how to fit the SQL inside of it.

What is the right way to achieve this with rails? I would like to avoid wrong patterns and low readability.

Thanks!

Comment: I've removed the postgresql + sql tags from this question, as it's Ruby / Ruby on Rails specifically that you're having the problems with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this by adding a method to your model that will perform the desired calculation and return the boolean value.